# Configure encryption types allowed for Kerberos disabled

Tags: windows, kerberos, kdc

I used the Configure encryption types allowed for Kerberos in a KDC on Windows Server 2012 R2 for few times but now it's disabled. I don't know why or how to enable it. Help will be appreciated :)

The Disabled Configuration Panel

[image: The Disabled Configuration Panel]

Answer (score 0):

A group policy is present that sets this value.

You cannot override a group policy with the local policy, so that means you need to either remove the group policy or update it to include the necessary encryption types.